# Ember Data: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm new to **Ember CLI** and I've been trying to push data to hasMany relationship after it has been created, but I'm getting this weird error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` Everything seems to be fine `this.store.createRecord()` is working but `.findRecord .push .peekRecor`d is not working.

**My controller**:

```
var VideoToAdd = this.store.find('video', this.get('ActiveCanvas'));
console.log(this.get('ActiveCanvas'));
VideoToAdd.get('hotspots').push(newHotspot);
```

**Video Model**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr(),
  file: DS.attr(),
  hotspots: DS.hasMany('hotspot')
});
```

**Hotspot Model:**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr(),
  onVideo: DS.belongsTo('video'),
  toVideo: DS.attr()
});
```

Please tell me what's going wrong.

Comment: I think you want `VideoToAdd.get('hotspots').addObject(newHotspot)`, or `.addObjects` if it's an array of hotspots. You could also use `.pushObject` and `.pushObjects`, but using 'add' will check to make sure that the record doesn't already exist in the array, so it's a little bit safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The store's [find](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_find) method is an asynchronous method that returns a promise (actually a promise object). When you call `VideoToAdd.get('hotspots')` you get undefined because the promise hasn't resolved yet; the data simply isn't there. If you waited until the promise resolved, you would be fine.

```
this.store.find('video', this.get('ActiveCanvas')).then(function(VideoToAdd) {
    VideoToAdd.get('hotspots').pushObject(newHotspot);
});
```

And to echo what Tom Netzband said in the comments, you'll want to use an Ember friendly method to add an object to the array. `pushObject` or `addObject` should work.

Comment: ahh totally didn't even notice the promise aspect of this. good catch.